# Not getting notifications for comment replies on public posts

Tags: facebook

If a friend responds to a comment on my post by tagging me, I am getting notifications but when I comment anywhere on public, or closed facebook groups that I am part of, I am not getting a notification when they reply to my comment by tagging me. I have to go back and look at the post and there I will see my name listed at the beginning of the person's reply followed by the reply but my name is not clickable (it's just plain text) and I am not getting notifications for it.